# Handling a "complex" database in Android SQLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite

1 - Extending many times the SQLiteOpenHelper is wrong and wont work.
2 - Having a big class that extends SQLiteOpenHelper to handle (CRUD) 7 different classes is strange.

Is there an example to do this? CRUD many entities into my database without an enourmous and dependent class?

I can't seem to find examples bigger than 2 or 3 tables on Google.
Having a very big SQLiteOpenHelper with save methods for all of my entities is horrible.
ORM is not allowed on this project either.

Any help/directions?

Comment: I have apps with 20+ entities, and they work just fine. I created a base class for db-backed objects as well as a generic List class holding objects descending from those. The only thing the descendant classes generally need to implement is a `loadFromCursor()` and `getContentValues()`

Comment: Ok... can you point me the way you did it? Do you have an online example?

Comment: Sorry to say, I don't have time to sanitize code right now. But to point you in the right direction, my `DBObject` has three abstract methods: `void loadFromCursor( Cursor c )`, `ContentValues getContentValues()`, and `String getWhereClause()`. I also have empty implementations of `boolean isEqual( DBObject obj )` and `void clone( DBObject obj )` for change management. Based on the above, I can easily implement CRUD (which I called `store()`, `load()` and `delete()`). Only the descendant objects know their column names, so I'm not cluttering up my code with contract classes and such.

Comment: I would love to see the "sanitized code" for this. I really can't find good answers for this on the internet. When you find time for it, build a topic and aswer it here in StackOverflow, I'm pretty shure it will help a lot the community. Thanks.

Comment: I'm in the middle of a refactor, considering utilizing annotations and injection... once done, this will probably go public. I approached it the same way you did... the advertised pattern is fine for one or two tables, but anything beyond that gets pretty unwieldy. I also didn't want to create something from scratch for each project, so that's how my solution came about.

Comment: I will set @sajmon_d aswer as the correct one. But PLEASE... PM me when you public your solution... Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Having a very big SQLiteOpenHelper with save methods for all of my
>   entities is horrible.

Do you think that good designated application will have only a few code lines?

In Android extending from `SQLiteOpenHelper` is the best choice as possible. It wraps all required logic and work with it is in my opinion very comfortable. But all requires correct implementation.

> Extending many times the SQLiteOpenHelper is wrong and wont work

Most likely there is not a problem with `SQLiteOpenHleper` but wrong implementation and usage i think.

How you meant, ORM frameworks for example as `ORMLite` is not allowed so my suggestion is to use `SQLiteOpenHelper` and make correct and clean implementation.

### Update:

> 7 save methods. 7 update methods. 7 delete mehotds. 7 select methods.
>   MANY other methods to get other data from the database. Is it the best
>   choice?

How i meant in comments this is problem of implementation. You really don't need 7 save methods above 7 tables. Here is my first idea. What about to create one universal method?

```
public class DataSourceTools {

   private SQLiteOpenHelper handler;
   private SQLiteDatabase db;

   public DataSourceTools(SQLiteOpenHelper handler) {
      this.handler = handler;
   }

   public void saveObject(String table, ContentValues data) {
      try {
         db = openWrite(this.handler);
         if (db != null) {
            db.insert(table, nullColumnHackName, data);
         }
      }
      finally {
         close(db);
      }
   }

   public void updateObject(String table, ContentValues dataToUpdate) {
      try {
         db = openWrite(this.handler);
         if (db != null) {
            String whereClause = "...";
            String[] whereArgs = {...};
            db.update(table, dataToUpdate, whereClause, whereArgs);
         }
      }
      finally {
         close(db);
      }
   }

   public void deleteObject(String table, ContentValues data) {
      try {
         db = openWrite(this.handler);
         if (db != null) {
            String whereClause = "...";
            String[] whereArgs = {...};
            db.delete(table, whereClause, whereArgs);
         }
      }
      finally {
         close(db);
      }
   }

   public Object findObject(String table, ContentValues data) {
      Object myObject = null; 
      Cursor c = null;
      try {
         String[] columns = {"id", "name", "lastname", ...};
         String selection = "id = ?";
         String[] selectionArgs = {data.getAsString("key_id")};
         c = db.query(table, columns, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null);
         if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            myObject = new Object();
            myObject.setId(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("id")));
            myObject.setName(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name")));
            myObject.setLastName(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("lastname")));
         }
         return myObject;
      }
      finally {
         if (c != null) {
            c.close()
         }
         close(db);
      }
   }

   public List<Object> findAll(String table) {
      List<Object> objects = new ArrayList<Object>(); 
      Object myObject = null; 
      Cursor c = null;
      try {
         String[] columns = {"id", "name", "lastname", ...};
         c = db.query(table, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
         if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            myObject = new Object();
            myObject.setId(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("id")));
            myObject.setName(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name")));
            myObject.setLastName(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("lastname")));
            objects.add(myObject);
         }
         return objects;
      }
      finally {
         if (c != null) {
            c.close()
         }
         close(db);
      }
   }

   private final synchronized SQLiteDatabase openWrite(SQLiteOpenHelper handler) {
      if (handler != null) {
         return handler.getWritableDatabase();
      }
      return null;
   }

   private final synchronized SQLiteDatabase openRead(SQLiteOpenHelper handler) {
      if (handler != null) {
         return handler.getReadableDatabase();
      }
      return null;
   }

   private final synchronized void close(SQLiteDatabase db) {
      if (db != null && db.isOpen()) {
         db.close();
      }
   }
}
```

**Note:** This is first concept, just now written especially for you so it needs updates: think about parameters of methods --> how to make better choice, usage of transactions, datasource as singleton, make some performance test for inserting, updating. All depend on character of application.

Comment: 7 save methods. 7 update methods. 7 delete mehotds. 7 select methods. MANY other methods to get other data from the database. Is it the best choice?

Comment: Now you are talking about implementation so 28 methods in one class in not good but this is problem of implementation not used technology :-

Comment: I'm setting this aswer as the correct one... is a good aproach, but yet quite unflexible in many ways. But thanks for writing it.

Comment: @MBarni - tell me these ways and i will make update? this is only concept and need to by updated depending on application requirements.

Comment: "Storing" pré-made querys to retrive/alter database data.

Comment: I'm trying... not my primary language... let me just try to implement a few things here... if it works, I'll give you some beer.

Comment: ok i will wait(also im not native speaker) and can you upvote my answer? it's little demotivating to have accepted answer with negative rating, many thanks.

Comment: @MBarni you mean select one object from db?or list of objects?

Comment: I'm trying to build a findByKey and a findAll with cursor... but with not much of a success.

Answer (score 0):

Using parameterized methods is preferable to using one method for each operation on each table. MBarni, can you provide an example of why this is not flexible enough for your needs?

Comment: @sajmon_d already provided a very flexible code design that I adapted for my needs...